# ttk Treeview selection_set can't accept spaces

Tags: python, treeview, ttk

I'm building a gui using tkk in python and I'm having trouble with the `Treeview` command `selection_set()`. I'm trying to use it to set the default selection when my program starts but it seems that it can't accept a string with spaces in it.

```
tree.selection_set("Sunset Grill")
```

Causes:

```
return self.tk.call(self._w, "selection", selop, items)
_tkinter.TclError: Item Sunset not found
```

Can anyone give any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try the following:

```
tree.selection_set('"Sunset Grill"')
```

I'm guessing this based on the code for `ttk.py` and my limited understanding of Tcl.  The call to `tree.selection_set()` calls `self.selection("set", items)`, which in turn calls `self.tk.call(self._w, "selection", selop, items)` where `selop` is `'set'` and items is the string initially passed to `selection_set()`.

I'm not sure if the `self.tk.call()` is doing any massaging of the arguments before passing them to Tcl as it's a call into the `_tkinter.c module` and I don't know enough about the Python/C interface to grok that code. `;)`

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly sorry for the late reply been away for a while.

Comment: How would you apply this approach when the string to set is a variable?

Answer (score 1):

try `tree.selection_set(["Sunset Grill"])`