# ttk Treeview: How to select a row?

Tags: python, treeview

This must be something simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the selection row in a Treeview using the `selection_set` method.  I am confused by the ttk documentation which sometimes refers to *`items`* and other times to *`iid`* for method arguments.  When I insert a row into the `Treeview`, am I not creating an item which I give the handle `iid`?

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk

root = Tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, displaycolumns='#all')
tree["columns"]=("1", "2", "3", "4")
tree.column("#0", width=70)
tree.column("1", width=70, anchor=Tk.CENTER)
tree.column("2", width=50, anchor=Tk.CENTER)
tree.column("3", width=50, anchor=Tk.CENTER)
tree.column("4", width=70, anchor=Tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("1", text="Column 1")
tree.heading("2", text="Column 2")
tree.heading("3", text="Column 3")
tree.heading("4", text="Column 4")
id2 = []
count = 0
item_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for item in item_list:
    id = tree.insert("", count, iid='Row %s'%count, text=item, values=('1', '2', '3', '4'))
    id2.append(id)
    count += 1

tree.selection_set('Row 0') # Doesn't work -- returns "_tkinter.TclError:  Item Row not found"
tree.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1, side=Tk.RIGHT,padx=50)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-ttk-treeview-how-to-select-a-row.py", line 28, in <module>
    tree.selection_set('Row 0')  # Doesn't work -- returns "_tkinter.TclError:  Item Row not found"
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1402, in selection_set
    self.selection("set", items)
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1397, in selection
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "selection", selop, items)
_tkinter.TclError: Item Row not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have spaces embedded in the selection name. According to the answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691257/ttk-treeview-selection-set-cant-accept-spaces) you can use names like that simply by putting quotes around them:

```
tree.selection_set('"Row 0"')  # Does work.
```

The clue was in the error message said `Item Row not found` *not* `Item Row 0 not found`.